# Javascript value of input

Tags: javascript, textbox

This is supposed to calculate circumference, however, I am only getting a zero returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = false;
    var text = "This text shifts";

var Pi = 3.14159265;
    var dia = document.getElementById("txtdia");  
var circumf =  dia * Pi;

    function DisplayText(){

        document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = circumf;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form> 
   <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
   <input type="text" id="txt2"/><br>
   <input type="text" name="txtdia" />
   <input type="text" name="txtcircumf" />  
   <input type="button" value="Change Text" onclick="DisplayText()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `var Pi = ...;` you could just use the `Math` object's constants -- `Math.PI`

Comment: You forgot to give id attribute in `txtcircumf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem you have is that this script will run prior to your dom being ready.  As a result, even if you were properly grabbing the diameter's **value** it still wouldn't work, since `document.getElementById("txtdia")` wouldn't return anything.

I would just fetch the diameter's value *each time*.

```
function DisplayText(){
    var dia = document.getElementById("txtdia").value;  
    var circumf =  dia * Pi;
    document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = circumf;
}
```

---

The other option of course is to put this entire script **after** your html.  Ie

```
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = false;
    var text = "This text shifts";
```

Comment: Fantastic, just learning javascript. not sure how you got this question and then wrote the answer so fast, within 3 minutes. Crazy FAST! anyway Thanks so much, it works perfect.

Comment: @R2Builder - glad to help.  Be sure to accept the **best answer** by clicking the checkmark next to it.  (The **best** answer, which definitely may not be mine, given what others have posted)

Comment: Ok I see it now checked green

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 distinct issues which you need to fix for this to work correctly.

1. `txtcircumf` and `textdia` are the *name* of the elements, not the *id*, so using `document.getElementById` will fail.

   Fix: Add that as an id onto the elements in question:

   ```
   <input type="text" name="txtdia" id="txtdia" />
   <input type="text" name="txtcircumf" id="txtcircumf" />
   ```
2. The elements are not present when the script first runs. This is the issue described by @AdamRakis and his fix is probably best - always retrieve the value when you need it:

   ```
   function DisplayText(){
       var dia = document.getElementById("txtdia").value;  
       var circumf =  dia * Pi;
       document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = circumf;
   }
   ```
3. A minor point, but when you read the `.value` of a field you get text, as you are doing a mathematical equation it is common practice to ensure the value you're wouking with is numeric. You can use `parseFloat` for this:

   ```
   function DisplayText(){
       var dia = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtdia").value);  
       var circumf =  dia * Pi;
       document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = circumf;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple structural changes that improve the overall quality of your code :) (see the arrows for changes)

```
<html>
<body>
<form> 
   <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
   <input type="text" id="txt2"/><br>
   <input type="text" name="txtdia" />
   <input type="text" name="txtcircumf" />  
   <input type="button" id="derp" value="Change Text" /> //<-- added ID, removed inline JS
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("derp").onclick = function() { //<-- use this style instead of inline onclicks!
    var index = false;
    var text = "This text shifts";

    var dia = document.getElementById("txtdia").value; //<-- .value, not the whole element!  
    var circumf =  dia * Math.PI; //<-- Math.PI is an object constant, very handy
    document.getElementById("txtcircumf").value = circumf;
    //no more standard function!
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the above code causes Error in IE 9 >> Unable to set value of the property 'onclick': object is null or undefined 
on line 4

Comment: What error would that be? I forgot since you're doing math on an input you'll have to parsefloat the .value

Comment: Math.PI must need a library or somehting, when I use it I get "NaN" for an answer on stead of a cricumference. also error on line 4

Comment: No library needed sir, like I said you need to parsefloat the element value, else you'll be doing math with a string with will yield `NaN` (not a number)

Comment: thanks all... I tried each one but the first one does the trick.